# Python timeout lock with option to stop

Tags: c#, python, python-3.x

I using python 3.6 for sync multiple threads. I have a "master thread" that gives work for all the other threads. When a worker thread is finish work, it signal the master thread to give him more work.

In order to achive that, the master thread is waiting for one (or more) threads to finish before collecting new data to process.

```
while True:
    while freeWorkers > 0:
        # Give the worker more work...

    time.sleep(5) # wait for 5 seconds before checking if we got free workers.
```

Basiclly, it's working. I want to upgrade it in that way: after a worker finish it job, it report some how to the "master" thread. Because master thread is really quick, in most cases the master thread will be sleeping... I want to make him stop sleeping, what will trigger giving more work for the free workers.

In C#, I did this trick in that way:
An object to handle the syncing around

```
public object SyncingClock { get; private set; } = new object();
```

Entering sleep in that way:

```
lock (SyncingClock)
    Monitor.Wait(SyncingClock, 5000);
```

Worker thread report completion in that way:

```
lock (SyncingClock)
    Monitor.Pulse(SyncingClock);
```

So, I looking to way to perform this C# trick in Python (or any other alternative).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This done with `Condition` object.

```
self.conditon = threading.Condition()
```

For waiting to timeout or pulse, do:

```
with service.conditon:
    service.conditon.wait(5)
```

For notify:

```
with self.conditon:
    self.conditon.notifyAll()
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should look at eventdriven programming (https://emptypage.jp/notes/pyevent.en.html)

and not having a while loop polling for finished workers:

for example something like this:

```
def create_thread(self, work_finished_method):
    t = some_method_to_create_and prepare_a_thread()
    t.event_finished += work_finished_method
    return t

class MyThread:

    name = "SomeNameForTheThread"
    event_finished = event.Event(name + " has finished.")

    def finished(self):
        self.event_finished()

    def do_work:
        do_something()
        finished()
```

and when the `work_finished` method is called in the mainhthread you can assign new work to the thread.